# python error using tkinter root is not defined

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to use tkinter in python.

I imported tkinter using `from tkinter import TK`
and I defined root `root = TK()`

I use python-3 and I work on a Linux ubuntu
I also did install tkinter but it keeps giving me following error:

[image: here is a screenshot from the error]

I am not too experienced with python yet.
Please help me.

Comment: It is `Tk`, not `TK`.

Answer (score 0):

The better way is to use this one
`import tkinter as tk`
instead of from `tkinter import TK`

[like this image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oN9Tq.png)

Comment: Why don't you post the code in text instead of image?  Also OP issue is not related to how the module is imported.